# Get file tree with Gson library

Tags: java, json, file, gson

I'm trying to get a JSON file with the structure of a directory, including files and subdirectories recursively.

Using the `apache-commons-io` library I get a list of subdirectories and files with the structure I want:

```
List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE,
                DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

But when I try to serialize it to a JSON file using the `Gson` library the returned String contains only the root path:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(files.get(0));
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "path": "/storage/emulated/0"
}
```

How can I get the JSON object with all the subdirectories and files included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your question.
For example, what I found are:

- Assumptions

  - As it was pointed out in an answer by [Hemant Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295987/hemant-patel), `files.get(0)` simply returns the first child. If will definitely fail if there are no children.
  - Also, I have never used Apache Commons IO, but it turns out that `DirectoryFileFilter` accepts directories only, and you need `TrueFileFilter` as it's pointed out in Java docs.
- Memory and general performance issues

  - I'm not sure how Apache Commons IO works behind the scenes, but returning an in-memory collection, `LinkedList`, is likely a memory issue. For example, Google Guava [`fileTreeTraverser`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#fileTreeTraverser()) returns traverser that allows to iterate through an iterable not requiring a whole list to be stored in memory (however it would require a custom serializer/deserializer pair for `Iterable` and detecting directory enter/leave anyway).
  - Serializing a potentially large collection to a string using `String Gson.toJson(...)` is another memory issue. If possible, you should consider streaming.
- Compatibility issues

  - I wouldn't recommend serialize `File` directly, because Gson does not provide a serializer/deserializer pair for it. As of the latest Gson version 2.8.4 it uses `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter` so it uses `File` fields. If the `File` internal structure changes for whatever reason, you won't be able to deserialize it. Also, having a single `path` property does not let you distinguish between directories and files.

Having that said, you might want to traverse a file directory yourself converting every directory and file to any representation you want consuming as little files as possible.

The below interface would allow you to build any JSON structure. For example:

- A super-simple flat list:

```js
[
    "./file1",
    "./file2",
    "./dir1",
    "./dir1/file1",
    "./dir1/file2",
    "./dir2",
    "./dir2/file1"
]
```

- A typed flat list:

```js
[
    {"type": "file", "path": "./file1"},
    {"type": "file", "path": "./file2"},
    {"type": "directory", "path": "./dir1"},
    {"type": "file", "path": "./dir1/file1"},
    {"type": "file", "path": "./dir1/file2"},
    {"type": "directory", "path": "./dir2"},
    {"type": "file", "path": "./dir2/file1"}
]
```

- A directory/file JSON object where an object indicates a directory whereas a `null` indicates a file:

```js
{
    "file1": null
    "file2": null,
    "dir1": {
        "file1": null,
        "file2": null
    },
    "dir2": {
        "file1": null
    }
}
```

- A directory/file JSON array where a string indicates a file whereas an object indicates a directory:

```js
[
    "file1"
    "file2",
    {
        "name": "dir1",
        "children": [
            "file1",
            "file2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "dir2",
        "children": [
            "file1"
        ]
    }
]
```

```java
interface IDirectoryWalkListener {

    void onEnterDirectory(int level, @Nonnull File directory)
            throws IOException;

    void onFile(@Nonnull File file)
            throws IOException;

    void onLeaveDirectory(int level, @Nonnull File directory)
            throws IOException;

}
```

```java
final class DirectoryWalk {

    private DirectoryWalk() {
    }

    static void walk(final File root, final IDirectoryWalkListener listener)
            throws IOException {
        walk(0, root, listener);
    }

    private static void walk(final int level, final File root, final IDirectoryWalkListener listener)
            throws IOException {
        if ( !root.isDirectory() ) {
            throw new IOException(root + " must be a directory");
        }
        @Nullable
        final File[] files = root.listFiles();
        if ( files == null ) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot list files in " + root);
        }
        listener.onEnterDirectory(level, root);
        for ( final File file : files ) {
            if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
                walk(level + 1, file, listener);
            } else {
                listener.onFile(file);
            }
        }
        listener.onLeaveDirectory(level, root);
    }

}
```

```java
final class ToFlatJsonArrayDirectoryWalkListener
        implements IDirectoryWalkListener {

    private final JsonWriter jsonWriter;

    private ToFlatJsonArrayDirectoryWalkListener(final JsonWriter jsonWriter) {
        this.jsonWriter = jsonWriter;
    }

    static IDirectoryWalkListener get(final JsonWriter jsonWriter) {
        return new ToFlatJsonArrayDirectoryWalkListener(jsonWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterDirectory(final int level, @Nonnull final File directory)
            throws IOException {
        if ( level == 0 ) {
            jsonWriter.beginArray();
        }
        jsonWriter.value(directory.getPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFile(@Nonnull final File file)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.value(file.getPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveDirectory(final int level, @Nonnull final File directory)
            throws IOException {
        if ( level == 0 ) {
            jsonWriter.endArray();
        }
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```java
// Writing to a string is a potential performance and memory issue
final Writer out = new StringWriter();
final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(out);
jsonWriter.setIndent("\t");
DirectoryWalk.walk(root, ToFlatJsonArrayDirectoryWalkListener.get(jsonWriter));
System.out.println(out);
```

```java
final Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out) {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        // do not close System.out
    }
};
final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(out);
jsonWriter.setIndent("\t");
DirectoryWalk.walk(root, ToFlatJsonArrayDirectoryWalkListener.get(jsonWriter));
out.flush();
```

Example output if `root` is `./target`:

```
[
    "./target",
    "./target/data",
    "./target/data/journal",
    "./target/data/journal/server.lock",
    "./target/classes",
    "./target/classes/com",
    "./target/classes/com/google",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors/InterceptorFactory$InterceptorAdapter.class",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors/InterceptorFactory$1.class",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors/InterceptorFactory.class",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors/JsonPostDeserializer.class",
    "./target/classes/com/google/gson/interceptors/Intercept.class",
    ...
]
```

In order to restore files structure from the JSON, you need a `JsonReader` (to use memory in a more efficient way) or a custom deserializer (if you're fine to read all stuff into memory).

Answer (score 0):

What you print, what you get:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(files.get(0)); // one file
{
  "path": "/storage/emulated/0"
}


String json = gson.toJson(files); // all files
[
  {
    "path": "/storage/emulated/0"
  },
  {
    "path": "/storage/emulated/0/dir1"
  },
  {
    "path": "/storage/emulated/dir2"
  }
]
```